# Android java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Tags: java, android, android-layout, classcastexception

I get the following exception in Android when clicking a button to take me from an activity to another (I'm new in Android development, so it may not be the brightest of questions):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

I have tried cleaning the project several times, I've tried the option Fix Project Properties from Android Tools,  I've checked my xml for mistakes but I just can't seem to figure this out. I have to mention that the button worked well for some time until this exception occurred.

Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/editCustomerPhone"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".CustomerInfoActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_new_delivery" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Insert Customer Data:"
        android:textColor="@color/light_blue"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</FrameLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editCustomerName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textColor="@color/light_blue" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submitInfoBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editCustomerName"
    android:text="Submit Info"
    android:textColor="@color/light_red" 
    android:onClick="submitCustomerInfo"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editCustomerPhone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editCustomerName"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/TextView01"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:textColor="@color/light_red" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:text="Name:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editCustomerPhone"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Email:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editCustomerEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editCustomerPhone"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:textColor="@color/light_green" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editCustomerName"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="Phone:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif" />
```

Here is my onCreate method in the activity that throws the exception:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_info);

    this.editMail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCustomerEmail);
    this.editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCustomerName);
    this.editPhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCustomerPhone); // the exception points me here
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you code says :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/editCustomerPhone"
```

`editCustomerPhone` is a relativelayout.

Comment: and it is an EditText. @barca_d just remove the android:id attribute from the RelativeLayout.

Comment: How did I miss that... I guess it's the Eclipse designer's fault for making the xml behind so messy and unordered

Comment: this sort of issue triggers a warning saying `Duplicate id, already defined ...` in the xml editor. There could be something wrong with your configuration, though.

Answer (score 2):

> android:id="@+id/editCustomerPhone"

remove this line

from below tag

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/editCustomerPhone"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context=".CustomerInfoActivity" >
```

you have set it twice. One for relative layout one for edittext

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when my main **activity.xml** did not have the include statement to my **content.xml** file.

Once i added these lines back into my main **activity.xml** file, everything was fine again.

```
    <include
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    layout="@layout/content" />
```