# NDK location not found

Tags: android, android-ndk, artoolkit

I get the error message "Error:Specified NDK location does not exists.  Please ensure ndk.dir in local.properties file or ANDROID_NDK_HOME is configured correctly." when I try to run a sample android application from [ARToolKit](http://artoolkit.org/documentation/) in Android Studio 2.2.2. This application has also parts (libraries) written in c++ which is why the NDK is necessary.

I have tried to set the environmental variable ANDROID_NDK_HOME and the property ndk.dir in the local properties file and I still get this message.

I installed the NDK using the built in SDK manager and it was correctly downloaded and installed at the location specified in the variable.

I use a Windows 7 64 bits computer and the target SDK version is 23.

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow the instructions from here: http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=4_Android:android_native

In short:

From the android directory run ./build.sh that is how ARToolKit builds the native libraries for each example project. If you want to use the nativeExamples as well you need to run the ./build_native_examples.sh too.

Also, unfortunately, ARToolKit needs three different environment variables to be set. Two of them need to point to the NDK:

- Set ANDROID_HOME to indicate the path to root folder of the downloaded Android SDK.
- Set ANDROID_NDK_ROOT to indicate the path to root folder (most likely, “ndk-bundle”) of the downloaded NDK. The ANDROID_HOME environment variable can be used to help define NDK. ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle
- Set NDK to the same path as ANDROID_NDK_ROOT. NDK=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT
- Set PATH to include a path to the ndk-build[.cmd] script file, that is, the path to the root folder of the NDK. The NDK environment variable can be used to help define the added path.

Please note that the variable is called ANDROID_NDK_ROOT not ANDROID_NDK_HOME.

Important:

As you are on Windows, you need to use the GitBash to run the *.sh scripts. The Windows command line does not have the commands used in the sh scripts, that is why you need to install and use GitBash.

That should you get going.

There is also the artoolkit.org/community/forum to help you along with questions.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
So, this week I have been trying to do everything said in this documentation. Since it still didn't work I thought of changing to windows 10, because it was saying that "ARToolKit actively supports the Android development systems of Mac OS X 9+ and Windows Desktop 8.1 and 10" and then I started all over again.

When I am trying to ensure I "have a working Android SDK and NDK environment before continuing", trying the [Hello-JNI tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) that the author proposes

Comment: ... I can't complete it because I get the error "error:cannot find symbol class TextView on the step #6 of the "Add JNI Code Into Project" chapter. I have found answers at relative errors and they are all saying that it's a gradle problem but I haven't found the way to fix it.
(I'm totally new in programming btw)

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: If anyone has same problem:
1. At _MainActivity.java_ check if there is the _import android.widget.TextView;_. If not, import it.
2. If you have a new error saying smth like _Android java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView_ then you have to check both _content-main.xml_ and _activity-main.xml_ to see if the _android:id="@+id/jni_msgView"_ is duplicated. It has to exist only in _TextView_. Same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951847/android-java-lang-classcastexception-android-widget-relativelayout-cannot-be-ca)